# What do the symbols in the header of Hunter-Net Mean?

Tags: world-of-darkness, hunter-the-reckoning

Hunter-Net is the messageboard/list serv archive that the Imbued use in Hunter: The Reckoning. The header to the site looks like this:

[image]

What do the symbols (hunter code) in the header mean? The symbol on the right means "hope", but I can't find the symbol on the left in any of the dozen or so Hunter books I own. It also doesn't appear on the WhiteWolf fan wiki.

So what does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking it up, I found the symbol [here](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Hunter:_The_Reckoning_symbols) that refers to it as "protected".

[image]

Comment: The same source lists the other symbol as “hope.”

Comment: This matches the print version of Hunter: The Reckoning. So despite my claims, it was both in the book and the fan wiki.